# Database default value being used when explicit value set

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Not sure whether this is a known issue or not. But it seems that when inserting a new entity into the database if the StatusId int property has an explicit value of 0, this value is ignored and the database default value of 1 is used instead.

I have read this maybe due to the fact that the CLR type defaults are ignored so for an int a 0 value would be ignored therefore it uses the database default.

Updating the entity seems to be unaffected.

I don't want to have to change my entity property to int? as it always has a value.

Has this issue been fixed ?

I have an Entity as follows:

```
public class FuelGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public enum StatusEnums
{
    Inactive = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Other = 2
}
```

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    private const string SQL_NEWID_FUNCTION = "(newid())";

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FuelGroup>(ConfigureFuelGroup);
    }

    private void ConfigureFuelGroup(EntityTypeBuilder<FuelGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValueSql(SQL_NEWID_FUNCTION);

        builder.Property(p => p.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(FuelGroupValidators.DescriptionMaxLength)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.ShortDesc)
            .HasMaxLength(FuelGroupValidators.ShortDescMaxLength)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.StatusId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValue((int)StatusEnums.Active);
    }
}
```

```
CREATE TABLE [FuelGroups] (
    [Id]                [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp]    [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWID()),
    [Description]        [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ShortDesc]            [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StatusId]            [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
)
```

*Further technical details*

*EF Core version:*

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />`

*Database Provider:*

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />`

*Operating system:*

Windows 7

*IDE:*

Visual Studio 2019 16.1.2

Comment: *Don't* use a GUID for a concurrency stamp. Use a `rowversion` column. No default value is going to work as a concurrency stamp, GUID or not,  simply because it *doesn't* change automatically when the data changes. `rowversion` on the other hand does, and is *guaranteed* to work reliably.

Comment: Apparently it's not fixed. There are a lot of similar questions in their GitHub issue tracker (the last being yours:), for instance [Allow update pipeline to push nulls and/or CLR defaults for store generated values #7199](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7199).